# Annotated Transformer - Why x + DropOut(Sublayer(LayerNorm(x)))?

Tags: transformer

Please clarify if the [Annotated Transformer](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/annotated-transformer/#encoder-and-decoder-stacks) Encoder LayerNorm implementation is correct.

[image]

[Transformer paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) says the output of the sub layer is `LayerNorm(x + Dropout(SubLayer(x)))`.

[image]

`LayerNorm` should be applied **after** the `DropOut(SubLayer(x))` as per the paper:

[image]

However, the [Annotated Transformer](https://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/annotated-transformer/#encoder-and-decoder-stacks) implementation does `x + DropOut(SubLayer(LayerNorm(x)))` where `LayerNorm` is applied **before** `Sublayer`, which is the other way around.

```
class SublayerConnection(nn.Module):
    """
    A residual connection followed by a layer norm.
    Note for code simplicity the norm is first as opposed to last.
    """

    def __init__(self, size, dropout):
        super(SublayerConnection, self).__init__()
        self.norm = LayerNorm(size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x, sublayer):
        "Apply residual connection to any sublayer with the same size."
        return x + self.dropout(sublayer(self.norm(x)))   # <--- LayerNorm before SubLayer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Karpathy: https://youtu.be/kCc8FmEb1nY?t=5729 it's more common to do pre-norm now vs. the post-norm formulation in the original paper. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.04745.pdf talks about some of the reasoning, mainly about stability of gradients during training. The earliest mention I could find of prenormalization is from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.10853.pdf): " Different to Vaswani et al. (2017) we apply layer normalization
before the self-attention and FFN blocks instead of after, as we find it leads to more effective training.
Sub-blocks are surrounded by a residual connection (He et al., 2015)."

It's possible that the Annotated Transformer was created after prenorm became the norm.